# Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu hover colour reverts to default as I click off of a menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a navbar with custom styles and for the most part it works well. However, I have used the following CSS to set the 'hover' colour for menu/dropdown items to green and while this mostly works, if I select a dropdown menu, the originating menu item shows green up until I click away (and close the dropdown), at which point it flashes a light grey (the default, I believe), before losing its colour. I can't for the life of me work out what I'm missing?

```
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #a2cc3a;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.nav .open>a:focus {background-color: transparent;/*or any color you want*/ }

Comment: Would you add some information about why this solves the issue please?

Answer (score 0):

That;s because you are not adding styles for the "active" state.
Try this:

```
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:active,
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.rpfb-navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:active,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:active,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus,
.rpfb-navbar .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:active {
    background-color: #a2cc3a;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. It seemed like the obvious fix to me, too, but it makes no difference (the "active" state also doesn't appear to have any added styles in bootstrap.css, either). There obviously is something, somewhere, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change dropdown color in LESS variables on official Bootstrap site while customizing.

```
@component-active-bg
```

is the variable you need to edit to change background color.

```
@component-active-color
```

is the variable to edit active item color.

Comment: I'm currently using bootstrap.min.css via CDN and then just adding my own styles with rpfb-* classes in a local stylesheet and have more or less the entire theme working as desired, so I'd rather find a fix that I can add to what I have, if possible?

Comment: Well, I've now tried this and it doesn't work anyway. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I still haven't found a fix for this. I've been ignoring it as an issue. Is there anything more that you can add? Changing the colour at source has made no difference and I can't find the source of the problem in the CSS output anywhere.